# Add own complicated form items into drupal form

Tags: javascript, forms, drupal

In Drupal, we can use hook_form_alter to add additional items in a form.

But if I have some form items, which is very difficult to use Drupal form API to express them. How to add them into the form ?

I have a complicated nested select, checkbox from category, to type, to item control, and
also include JavaScript to control their display.

Comment: For example, the Category, Type, Item includes complicated form items as following:


    <select name=category$c ...
    <select name=category$ctype$t ...
    <input type=checkbox name=category$ctype$titem$i

Answer (score 0):

Define your own element. An example of this is in the drupal examples module.